# Are there any rules on the positioning adverbs should take in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, word-order, adverb-position

For example:

> Ever wish you could share information **broadly**

Could it be rewritten to:

> Ever wish you could **broadly** share information

Are there any rules for the position of the adverbs.

Comment: I have found http://www.wordpower.ws/grammar/gramch24.html page that explain very well where to put the adverbs.

Comment: Sorry, no rule, so a comment instead. To me, the two phrases have different meanings. For the first, we are alreadt sharing information, but pondering the benefits or do so in a broad manner. In the second, we are considering starting to share information - but only in a qualified sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The positioning of the adverb should be based on the type of impact our sentence/question needs to make.

The first sentence:

> Ever wish you could share information broadly?

This would be more effective when used to catch the readers' attention, probably an advertisement/headline where the idea is to make all readers imagine "broadly".

The second one:

> Ever wish you could broadly share information?

This probably has more stress on the "information" rather than on "broadly". It would sound more apt in a paragraph, rather than in a headline.

Again, it depends on how the message needs to be sent across. Both options are correct.

Answer (score 12):

When an adverb modifies a verb, you can usually put it either before, between, or after:

Adverb = 'often', verb = 'go'

Before:

> Often, I go for long walks.

Between:

> I often go for long walks.

End:

> I go for long walks often.

These aren't all equally common; you would probably find the between position used the most.

In your example, you are asking a question, so the 'before' position can't really be used.

> Broadly, ever wish you could share information?

Just doesn't work.

But the between and end position are equally valid. I would say that, again, the between position sounds best.

> Ever wish you could broadly share information?

Comment: If someone said "Broadly, ever wish you could share information?" I would interpret 'broadly' as being applied to my explanation. In other words, they're asking for a broad overview of whether I wish I could share information, not asking about information that is broadly shared.

Comment: You define your "before" position as the adverb before the clause it modifies. In the OP's sentence, "broadly" modifies "share information", so "Ever wish you could broadly share information?" *does* use what you call the "before" position. // True, "Broadly" at the start of the whole sentence doesn't work, but that isn't because the sentence is a question, it's because the words "ever wish" in the main clause separate "Broadly" from the subsidiary clause it belongs in.

Comment: None of your first 3 examples has an auxiliary verb, so they fail to exemplify the full set of candidate positions for "broadly" in the OP's sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I always think the adverb should be placed as closely as possible to the word it modifies.  See how I did it in this sentence, with "as closely as possible"?