# Put the words in the correct order to make question

Tags: grammaticality, adverbs, word-order, questions

I am not a native speaker.

I am doing the exercise "Put the words in the correct order to make question" from my workbook.

I have this set of words:

> your / best / see / did / friend / when / last / you?

And I have three variants of the question:

> 1. When did you see your best friend **last**?
> 2. When did you see **last** your best friend?
> 3. When did you **last** see your best friend?

Which variant is correct and natural? Why?

Comment: You could even have "When did your best friend last see you?"

Comment: @DavidWallace, you are right, but main problem: where in sentence can I put "last"?

Comment: Best is 3.  1 is OK too.  See mikeY's answer.

Comment: Closely related to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence

Comment: Also, “When did your last friend see you best?”

Comment: When did you best see your last friend? When did you see your last best friend? When did you see your friend last best? All valid questions but with different angles.

Comment: General Reference - [And When Did You Last See Your Father](http://www.museumsyndicate.com/item.php?item=47039)

Comment: And don't forget, "*When last did you see your best friend?*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 and 3 are correct and natural questions. 2 is not.  If pushed to guess, I would say 3 is the more common form, although I frequently ask myself "Where did you see your keys last?"

There may be subtle nuances but both questions ask about the most recent time you encountered your best friend.

Answer (score 2):

- 2 is definitely incorrect
- 3 sounds the most natural to me
- 1 is fairly natural, but also potentially ambiguous, since *last* might just be taken as a verb (as in *to persist*, *to endure*, etc.) rather than as an adverb, i.e. *when did you see your best friend last [the course, the interrogation, etc.]*? Admittedly, it would be an unlikely misunderstanding, but if you want to be safe, choose option 3.

Comment: Since we don't know the intended meaning, 3 is just as good as 1. It just asks a different question about when you saw your best friend endure or at the back. For example: "I saw my best friend come in last in a race." "Oh? When did you see your best friend last?"

Answer (score 2):

- 3 is the correct answer.
  2 is grammatically wrong and the 'last' in the first option ambiguous as it can be considered as a verb.

Answer (score 1):

All that can be said with certainty is that

```
When did you see last your best friend?
```

is incorrect.

Rest depends on what the sentence is intended to mean. You can answer with either [1] or [3].