# Placing "first" in a sentence; would it change the meaning?

Tags: meaning, differences, adverbs, word-order

How does the meaning of the following two sentences differ?

> 1. I first wanted to tell you about it.
> 2. I wanted to tell you about it first.

Comment: #1 is unambiguous (I *wanted to tell you about it **before*** I do/did anything else). #2 is ambiguous - it might mean the same as #1, or it might mean I wanted to tell *you* before telling anyone else (or even, feasibly, I wanted to *tell* you about it before, for example, *demonstrating* it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Or #3, I wanted to tell you about it before anyone else told you about it. Btw, can you make your comment an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @MrHen: Personally, I think this is really more of an ELL question. To the extent that it fits at all on ELU, I'd say it's pretty much a duplicate of [Where to place 'only' relative to prepositions?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/115136/). As [John Lawler says there](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/115157/2637), it's all a matter of "focus" (of the word "only", or the word "first" - it's all the same to me).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: So should we close it appropriately?

Comment: @MrHen: You know me! I'm definitely "close-vote happy" here on ELU (the more so since ELL moved into beta). You I think are generally more tolerant in that respect. But between our first two comments I think we've given OP all the significant possibilities re interpreation of the specific examples. And John's answer per my link covers the general case for many other "positionally-dependent" modifiers. In short, the arguments for closing are sound, the Q isn't currently attracting any interest (present company excepted), and the OP has an answer. So yeah - I'll closevote if you will!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I chose GR. Feel free to pick a different reason. :)

Comment: @MrHen: I went for the "duplicate" option. Maybe a bit tenuous, but if three other people also decide to closevote, it'll be a "best of three" between them as to which reason comes out on top. Our comments should be enough for people to see what the issues are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there any rules on the positioning adverbs should take in a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence)

Answer (score 0):

You can clarify the meaning of #2 with "I wanted to be the first to tell you about it" or "I want to first tell you about it."

Answer (score 0):

#1 appears to indicate the action is putting more emphasis on the timing.

#2 appears to indicate the action is putting more emphasis on the order relative to the individual (i.e. before someone else) or some other action.