# Where to position "never" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverb-position

The following is a quote from Mr. Trump's statement.
Is it grammatical to say "We should have never been in Iraq"?
Shouldn't it be "We should never have been in Iraq"?

> "We should **have never** been in Iraq,” Mr. Trump said. “They lied, they
>   said there were weapons of mass destruction. There were none and they
>   knew that there were none.”

Comment: Or "We never should have been in Iraq."

Comment: Related question, [Are there any rules on the positioning adverbs should take in a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence).

Answer (score 1):

Position of **never** is tricky and all the below sentences are correct. But in order of preference and idiomatic usage:

> 1. We should **never** have been in Iraq.
> 2. We **never** should have been in Iraq.
> 3. We should have **never** been in Iraq.

The linked [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never+should+have%2Cshould+never+have%2Cshould+have+never%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cnever%20should%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20never%20have%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshould%20have%20never%3B%2Cc0) about *should have* and [this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=never+would+have%2Cwould+never+have%2Cwould+have+never&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) about *would have* seem to support the above order.

For further information, please see the [related answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence/9602#9602) posted to the question in my comment above.

Comment: I would bet that *never should'a* is the winner by two lengths.