# Adverb and verb position

Tags: adverb-position

I want you to clearly understand that excuses will not do.

I want you to understand clearly that excuses will not do.

My book says that second sentence is correct. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: The logic is that you aren't supposed to split an infinitive. For contemporary English, this rule is considered to be nonsense by many people. What I don't understand is why your book doesn't tell you why it thinks the first sentence is incorrect.

Comment: Related, [Are there any rules on the positioning adverbs should take in a sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence).