# Position of "ultimately" in a sentence

Tags: word-order

I have an american friend who tells me that this sentence:

[...] Since their absence results in a relevant market which is defined too broad, the two-sided critical loss analysis cannot be recommended **ultimately** for actual merger cases.

sounds more natural than this one:

[...] Since their absence results in a relevant market which is defined too broad, the two-sided critical loss analysis **ultimately** cannot be recommended for actual merger cases.

I'm no native English speaker, but the first one sounds weird to me. I would be very glad if I could have some more opinions on this - thanks!

Edit: I'm aware that there are (a lot) of other questions concerning the positioning of adverbs. However, since this is the last sentence in my abstract, I want the sentence to be perfect and not choose the "ultimately" at a random position. Maybe someone could explain which position would make the most sense / sounds the most natural.

Comment: I'd want 'broadly', 'recommended' and would prefer 'ultimately after 'cannot' (but choosing the other two positions I'd just consider differences in style).

Comment: Thank you, the "recommended" was a typo, just edited it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there any rules on the positioning adverbs should take in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence) Also [Should an adverb go before or after a verb?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9702/) and doubtless many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it right, the second example is far more natural sounding. However, purely as a stylistic preference, I would recommend switching "ultimately" and "cannot". Finally, instead of saying "defined too broad", I would say "too broadly defined".

The most natural sentence would read like this:

Since their absence results in a relevant market which is **too broadly defined**, the two-sided critical loss analysis cannot **ultimately** be recommended for actual merger cases.