# Question about adverb placement in these sentences

Tags: grammar, adverbs, questions, adverb-position

I'm confused about the adverb placement. I heard that adverbs that indicate manner should be placed at the end of a sentence, but I have seen many sentences that do not follow this rule. For some sentences, it sounds awkward if I place the adverb at the very end.

Which is correct?

> In order to help him learn the concepts and techniques **skillfully**, did you ensure that you prepare the lessons?
>
> Did you define the terms to students **precisely, clearly, and nicely**?

OR

> In order to help him **skillfully** learn the concepts and techniques, did you ensure that you prepare the lessons?
>
> Did you **precisely, clearly, and nicely** define the terms to students?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any rules on the positioning adverbs should take in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence)

Comment: The rule you heard is not a rule. It's just something you **can** do, not something you **have to** do. Adverbs can go in lots of places in a sentence; the end is often possible, but it's not the only one. There is no single rule for placement, and a lot of variation. Speakers' choice, usually.

Comment: The sentence is a hair awkward either way.