# She acted as though she was subtle. She never was subtle. Or: She was never subtle

Tags: grammar, word-choice

She acted as though she was subtle. Then:

1 She never was subtle
2 She was never subtle

The first one sounds right to me although the second one seems to be the grammatically correct one? Or are both grammatically correct?

Comment: If you consider "never" as modifying "was" it should go before "was"; if it's modifying "subtle" it should go immediately before "subtle". With most verbs you would say the former e.g. "She never appeared subtle", but it's very possible to have "never subtle" as an adjectival expression following "was".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any rules on the positioning of adverbs  n a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence) There is also a question actually addressing the distribution of 'never' (ie where it occurs in a sentence). 'Never' can **never** 'modify' _subtle_ in such a sentence; rather, positioning it before 'was' switches the emphasis in the sentence. Here, the first variant is not the natural choice (though perfectly grammatical), and although adding gravitas, isn't my choice.

Comment: So which one is right in this case? The first one or the second one?

Comment: Shouldn't it be *as though she **were** subtle*, though?

Comment: why would it be were?

Comment: Because of the _subjunctive mood_, eh?

Comment: It's increasingly rare to use the subjunctive in informal writing or speech.