# Are there rules or style considerations to the ordering of adverbs as modifiers to verbs and adjectives?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

When modifying a verb with an adverb, I noticed that you can swap the order in most cases without any loss of meaning. For instance:

> She ran quickly *versus* She quickly ran

Is there any reason to prefer or exclude the first or second version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any rules on the positioning adverbs should take in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9600/are-there-any-rules-on-the-positioning-adverbs-should-take-in-a-sentence) To summarise, (1) Adverbs may take different positions in a sentence pretty (but not totally) freely. (2) Different adverbs have different distributions. (3) Distinct classes of adverbs (eg frequency) tend to behave similarly within the class. (4) When different sites are available, different emphases can be achieved.

Comment: Notice that here, 'She ran quickly.' stands as a complete thought and makes a sensible sentence. She was a fast runner. 'She quickly ran' needs say a PP to sound natural ('She quickly ran over to the beach'). This could well mean she didn't delay setting off, whereas 'She ran quickly over to the beach' again describes her running speed.